# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory while trying to import stockfish engine

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to use the Stockfish chess engine for a project and I'm trying to import the engine (stockfish.app). I'm using the following code:

```
import subprocess

engine = subprocess.Popen("/Users/_/Downloads/stockfish.app", universal_newlines=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
```

but I'm getting the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/_/Documents/Python/AI/Chess/Chess/stockfishAI.py", line 3, in <module>
    engine = subprocess.Popen("/Users/_/Downloads/stockfish.app", universal_newlines=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/_/Downloads/stockfish.app': '/Users/_/Downloads/stockfish.app'
```

I'm not sure why this is happening as I've copied the directory exactly.
Here are the files in the directory

```
Contents

./Contents:
Info.plist  PkgInfo     _CodeSignature
MacOS       Resources   _MASReceipt

./Contents/MacOS:
Stockfish

./Contents/Resources:
AppIcon.icns            pawn_b.pdf
Assets.car          pawn_w.pdf
Base.lproj          queen_b.pdf
Binaries.entitlements       queen_w.pdf
bishop_b.pdf            rook_b.pdf
bishop_w.pdf            rook_w.pdf
en.lproj            stockfish-arm64
king_b.pdf          stockfish-x86-64
king_w.pdf          stockfish-x86-64-bmi2
knight_b.pdf            stockfish-x86-64-sse41-popcnt
knight_w.pdf            stockfish-x86-64-vnni256
nn-cb26f10b1fd9.nnue

./Contents/Resources/Base.lproj:
MainMenu.nib            SFMDocument.nib
Preferences.nib         SFMPreferenceCellView.nib

./Contents/Resources/en.lproj:
Credits.rtf     InfoPlist.strings

./Contents/_CodeSignature:
CodeResources

./Contents/_MASReceipt:
receipt
```

I don't know if me being on Mac has anything to do with it, as from the examples of importing stockfish I've seen, most of them are on Windows (importing a .exe file instead of a .app)
Please help if possible, as I am completely puzzled by this error.

Comment: can you list the file and permissions of `/Users/_/Downloads/stockfish.app` and share the o/p

Comment: @mukundghode , I have added a list of files in the directory and the output is already there.

Comment: can you do `ls Users`, `ls Users/_` and `ls Users/_/Downloads`; and show us the outputs

Comment: @ABC , ls Users gives me: 
```Shared  name1 name2 ``` 

```ls Users/_ ``` gives me: 
```
Applications
Credits.txt
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Library
Movies
Music
Pictures
Procfile
Public
PycharmProjects
books.db
edb_postgis_2_5_pg12.app.zip
edb_postgis_2_5_pg12.app.zip-20200731131432
fnejhfb.xlsx
get-pip.py
machine_learning_examples
opt
requirements.txt
runtime.txt
script1.py
static
templates
```

Comment: and ```ls Users/_/Downloads``` gives me:
```
chromedriver                                          heroku
pip-download-0.0.6                                pip_download-0.0.6-py3-none-any.whl
pycharm-community-2020.2.2.dmg       python-3.9.0-macosx10.9.pkg
Stockfish    
```

Comment: @user14621114 do `ls -l /Users/_/Downloads/stockfish*`

Comment: @mukundghode just one directory, ```Contents```

Comment: so this file `/Users/_/Downloads/stockfish.app` is not present, hence the error @user14621114

Comment: OK, I've found my error, I just realised I forgot to put a capital letter for Stockfish, but I am now getting the following error:

Comment: .
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/_/Documents/Python/AI/Chess/Chess/stockfishAI.py", line 5, in <module>
    engine = subprocess.Popen("/Users/_/Downloads/Stockfish", universal_newlines=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
```

Comment: ```
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/_/Downloads/Stockfish'
```

Comment: @user14621114 share some more details on code! what are you trying to achieve, which part is getting failed and also the code snippet. not just 2 lines of code

Comment: @mukundghode , sorry, but so far I'm only running 2 lines of code, and I haven't written any more. As for what I'm trying to achieve, I'm trying to use the stockfish chess engine. Sorry for the lack of information, but thats all there is right now.